# Self-intersecting geometry removal

Tags: mesh, modifiers, vertices, geometry

I'm working on a number of icons for 3-D printing. I'm having an issue where I've traced out the object as linked edges and vertices, and then gone through the following process:

Convert to curve.
In the curve options, extrude to add "height".
Convert back to mesh.
Apply solidify modifier.

This has left me with an object that is as I need it, but has also left some self-intersecting geometry that I would like to remove, so that I'm not getting overlapping faces inside the geometry etc.

[image: Image of icon with geometry]
[image: Close-up of intersecting geometry]
[image]

I've tried the:
Ctrl+F > Intersect (knife) but it doesn't seem to be simplifying the geometry as I need it
Boolean modifier using a cube around the object, and doing all three available operations. Nothing seems to happen here.

I have the .blend file here in a dropbox folder
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c05dvx6vforyx1y/AAB_bYT-gw0Z40l0AGKju9tga?dl=0

Comment: Hello :). This definitely looks like a perfect job for the *Boolean modifier.* You just need to separate your mesh into different objects for it to work.

Comment: Ah you're definitely right. I hadn't thought of that. That gets me new vertices at the intersect points, and though it leaves the intersect area with a lot of mess, it's pretty easily manually cleaned up so that will do nicely. Thank you! :)

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with your project.